# How to select groups from nested data in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have grouped data and `nest()` seems to be a create options to quickly summarize it. I would likt to select groups based on information of the tibble list, namely the number of observations. How can I access these numbers?

```
library(tidyr)
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>%
  nest()

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  continent data              
  <fct>     <list>            
1 Asia      <tibble [396 x 5]>
2 Europe    <tibble [360 x 5]>
3 Africa    <tibble [624 x 5]>
4 Americas  <tibble [300 x 5]>
5 Oceania   <tibble [24 x 5]> 

# How to select continents with more than 350 observations?
```

I tried combinations of `sample_n()` but of course every element of the nested data has size 1. How can I access the information about number of observations which I can see so easily from my console output for further selections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution (and extremely similar to r2evans) could be achieved using `map_lgl()` from `library(purrr)` like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  filter(purrr::map_lgl(data, ~ nrow(.x) > 350))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   continent [5]
#>   continent data              
#>   <fct>     <list>            
#> 1 Asia      <tibble [396 x 5]>
#> 2 Europe    <tibble [360 x 5]>
#> 3 Africa    <tibble [624 x 5]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Untested.

```r
gapminder %>%
  group_by(continent) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(n = sapply(data, NROW)) %>%
  filter(n > 300)
```

or just

```r
gapminder %>%
  group_by(continent) %>%
  nest() %>%
  filter(sapply(data, NROW) > 300)
```

You can replace `sapply` with `purrr::map_int`.